# Show tab class after clicking jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi guys I am the totally beginner in JS , I have added tab slider to my html in the tab menu i have 3 categories All ,Creative and Branding, how i can show div after clicking one of the li ? I have added classes to the li and created 2 divs for the images, but what should i do next ? Here is some code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("ul li").click(function(e) {

  // make sure we cannot click the slider
  if ($(this).hasClass('slider')) {
    return;
  }

  /* Add the slider movement */

  // what tab was pressed
  var whatTab = $(this).index();

  // Work out how far the slider needs to go
  var howFar = 160 * whatTab;

  $(".slider").css({
    left: howFar + "px"
  });

  /* Add the ripple */

  // Remove olds ones
  $(".ripple").remove();

  // Setup
  var posX = $(this).offset().left,
      posY = $(this).offset().top,
      buttonWidth = $(this).width(),
      buttonHeight = $(this).height();

  // Add the element
  $(this).prepend("<span class='ripple'></span>");

  // Make it round!
  if (buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
    buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
  } else {
    buttonWidth = buttonHeight;
  }

  // Get the center of the element
  var x = e.pageX - posX - buttonWidth / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - posY - buttonHeight / 2;

  // Add the ripples CSS and start the animation
  $(".ripple").css({
    width: buttonWidth,
    height: buttonHeight,
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  }).addClass("rippleEffect");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container3">
        <h1>OUR PORTFOLIO</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem exciting
          ipsum lore portfolio</p>
          <div class="portfolio">
            <ul>
      <li class="all">All</li>
      <li class="creative">Creative</li>
      <li class ="branding">Branding</li>
      <li class="slider"></li>

    </ul>

    <div class="photo" id="photo"style="display:none">
      <img src="img/icon2.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="photo2" id="photo2"style="display:none">
      <img src="img/icon3.png"/>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: How you determine which div is associated with respective li?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what your question is,hope this is what you are looking

```js
$('.all').click(function(e){
$('.hide').removeClass('hide')
})

$('.creative').click(function(e){
$('.photo').removeClass('hide')
$('.photo2').addClass('hide')
})

$('.branding').click(function(e){
$('.photo2').removeClass('hide')
$('.photo').addClass('hide')
})
```

```css
.hide
{
display:none

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container3">
    <h1>OUR PORTFOLIO</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem exciting
      ipsum lore portfolio</p>
      <div class="portfolio">
        <ul>
  <li class="all">All</li>
  <li class="creative">Creative</li>
  <li class ="branding">Branding</li>
 

</ul>

<div class="photo hide" id="photo" >
  <img src="img/icon2.png"/>
</div>
<div class="photo2 hide" id="photo2" >
  <img src="img/icon3.png"/>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @vladxvlad can you please approve if this works,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grab the clicked element's class and then show/hide div based on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("ul li").click(function(e) {


var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');

if(currentClass == "all") {
  $("#photo").css("display","block");
} else if (currentClass == "creative") {
  $("#photo2").css("display","block");
}



// make sure we cannot click the slider
if ($(this).hasClass('slider')) {
  return;
}

/* Add the slider movement */

// what tab was pressed
var whatTab = $(this).index();

// Work out how far the slider needs to go
var howFar = 160 * whatTab;

$(".slider").css({
  left: howFar + "px"
});

/* Add the ripple */

// Remove olds ones
$(".ripple").remove();

// Setup
var posX = $(this).offset().left,
    posY = $(this).offset().top,
    buttonWidth = $(this).width(),
    buttonHeight = $(this).height();

// Add the element
$(this).prepend("<span class='ripple'></span>");

// Make it round!
if (buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
  buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
} else {
  buttonWidth = buttonHeight;
}

// Get the center of the element
var x = e.pageX - posX - buttonWidth / 2;
var y = e.pageY - posY - buttonHeight / 2;

// Add the ripples CSS and start the animation
$(".ripple").css({
  width: buttonWidth,
  height: buttonHeight,
  top: y + 'px',
  left: x + 'px'
}).addClass("rippleEffect");
});
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide/show image base on ClassName:

```js
$('.container3 li').click(function(e){
 let className = $(this).attr('class');
 if(className == "all"){ //if all tab pressed
    $("#portfolio-gallery .photo").show(200);
  }else{
    $("#portfolio-gallery .photo").hide();
    $("#portfolio-gallery .photo."+className).show(200);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container3">
      <h1>OUR PORTFOLIO</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum lorem exciting ipsum lore portfolio</p>
      <div class="portfolio">
      
       
       <ul>
        <li class="all">All</li>
        <li class="creative">Creative</li>
        <li class ="branding">Branding</li>
       </ul>

    <div id="portfolio-gallery">
     <div class="photo creative" >
       <img src="img/icon2.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="photo branding" >
       <img src="img/icon3.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="photo branding" >
       <img src="img/icon2.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="photo branding" >
       <img src="img/icon3.png"/>
     </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```